# Localhost react app not receiving cookie from Heroku hosted node API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cookies

I am able to log in and out with POSTMAN through the heroku hosted node API.
In my react application, the API call with AXIOS (withcredentials:true) does not set the passport cookies, causing the session to not persist. Localhost react and Localhost server does not have this problem.

HEROKU SERVER SIDE, I have the following code:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
})); 
app.enable('trust proxy');
mongoose.connect(dbconfig.url, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false });

// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser('street'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'katsura street',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection },)
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I have checked that the cookie parser is above the session,
the session is initialized before passport.

Is my cors affecting my local reactapp? instead of localhost, am I supposed to reference my local computer's external API?

REACT SIDE:

```
 Axios.post(Config.ServerURL + 'auth/login',
            {email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password},
            {
                withCredentials: true
            }).then(result => {
                console.log(result.data);
        
        }).catch(error => {
            //make sure message doesn't crash
            if (error.response !== undefined) {
                try {
                    console.log(error.response);
                    this.setState({message: error.response.data.info.message})

                }catch(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the headers and seeing that the cookies are sent but filtered out, I came to a article: [heroku blog](https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie)

After 2019, Chrome and other browsers have cross domain cookies disabled to prevent CSRF attacks.

In my use case, I can just turn it off with the following on the Node API server:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'street',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
        sameSite:'none',
        secure:true
    },
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection },)
}));
```

changing samesite to none, will allow chrome to set your cookies with cross domains.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (I think) after deploying both the Vue UI and the Node API on Heroku. I assumed that since they are using the same domain (herokuapp.com), I have CORS set up correctly, I believe, and I'm using a paid version of Heroku with SSL, that  Chrome would send the cookie. (I'm using JWT's and relying on the client sending back the refresh token sent as an http-only cookie.) But I get no cookie back. It sounds like the above solution would work I just don't know how to apply it. In the server.js of my Node API? I'm not using session anywhere. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: After 12 hours of struggle, proxy:true + samesite:"none" did the magic. So thankful mate. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just setting, in the session settings, `cookie.sameSite` to `"none"`, and `proxy` to `true`.